# Is it still Rickrolling of the "roller" doesn't realize it?

Tags: intentionality, meme, philosophy-of-humor

Most older folks have been [Rickrolled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling) at least once. I was even "rolled" in an SE comment once.

A few days ago I found myself walking outdoors at night behind a backpack with an array of color LEDs, displaying a low resolution, short clip of of the music video [Never Gonna Give You Up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Never_Gonna_Give_You_Up).

The backpack wearer was *relatively* young and this took place in Taiwan, and [based on my experience here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/198513/51174) over the last decade+, chances are slim to none that they would know the actual significance of the display.

In once sense I certainly have not been Rickrolled *per se* because I did not click on a link while walking. But I did see blinking light out of the corner of my eye and moved to see what was it was, and Rick Astley and his distinctive moves was the last thing I expected.

I *felt* Rickrolled. But if we assume the backpack wearer didn't know of the meme, *was I?*

[image: Rickrolling backpack in Taiwan]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I understand the request; but I'm not sure how to clarify further "Have I been Rickrolled?" I've included details of the scenario and some definitions, what would help further?

Comment: Questions about colloquial meaning and use of words are off-topic here, some of them may be appropriate for English SE.

Comment: @Conifold I've linked to the definition/meaning for "Rickrolling *per se*" in my question so I'm not asking about that. In this case it feels like it was done to me (the experience of being Rickrolled - expecting one thing and cleverly being exposed to another, something that's meant to say "ha! you've just been Rickrolled!"), and yet the doer, or in this case "roller" didn't mean it. I don't know if  this is "unintended Rickrolling" or "Rickrolling by proxy" (surely whoever selected that clip for encoding into the backpack knew it's significance) or something else. There's something here.

Comment: So you answered your question as asked and the answer is no: "is it still?" -  no it isn't. If the intended question  is something else formulate what it is. Maybe you can extract a philosophy of language question out of it, but much of what is in the post, and Rickrolling as such, are likely irrelevant to that. So the post would have to be largely rewritten.

Comment: @Conifold If I felt I knew the answer to the question I would not post the question, and I'm not convinced anything I've written here is a real answer. This is Stack Exchange and it's on the OP to decide when there's an answer or not. At first I thought the notion was cute but later became *genuinely puzzled* by this so decided to post. If you've found what you're convinced is an answer in something I've written, then please post as an answer, then we can see how other's view it as an answer. The normal Stack Exchange way.

Comment: I believe that you are puzzled by "this", the problem is what "this" is. It is definitely not what you posted as the question, so I cannot answer it. What I can think of in the vicinity, like "when should we extend the meaning of a word to cases that it does not literally cover?" or "is it typical for language users to expand the use of words from prototypical cases to indirect allusions?" are not this SE questions either, hence the English SE suggestion.

Comment: @Conifold okay now that it's closed I'll refactor the question which may trigger a bump to the review-for-reopen queue.

Comment: @Conifold giving it some more thought, there's no "sound of one hand clapping in the forest" aspect to the situation after all. I was definitely Rickrolled by proxy. I can put it out of my mind now.